# StringTokenizer multiple lines

Tags: java

I have two files, called "ride.in" and "ride.out". The "ride.in" file contains two lines, one containing the string "COMBO" and the other line containing the string "ADEFGA".  As I said, each string is on separate lines, so "COMBO" is on the first line, while "ADEFGA" is on the second line in the "ride.in" file.
Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
File in = new File("ride.in");
File out = new File("ride.out");
String line;
in.createNewFile();
out.createNewFile();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out)));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    String sam =st.nextToken();
}
pw.close();
}
    }
```

I want to assign COMBO as one token and ADEFGA as another token, but in this code, both COMBO and ADEFGA are assigned to the sam string. How do I assign COMBO to one string, and ADEFGA to another string?

Comment: can you show the file data??

Comment: sorry I would have added the ride.in file but I don't know how to in stackoverflow. It is just a file I created using notepad, where the first line contains COMBO and the second line is ADEFGA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create variable number of variables.

Create a arraylist of string.

Change

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    String sam =st.nextToken();
}
```

to

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    myList.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

Now myList.get(0) will have "COMBO" and myList.get(1) will have "ADEFGA"

Comment: Thank you, very simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can read each line from the file into a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(new File("ride.in").toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset() );
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Fileutils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
List<String> words = FileUtils.readLines(new File("ride.in"), "utf-8");
```

`words` should now contain:

> ['COMBO', 'ADEFGA']

***Note: Adjust your `ride.in`'s file path accordingly***